# TypeScript: typed array as object property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type an array assigned to an object property:

```
const obj = {
  key: []
}
```

Is there a way to specify the type in-line? I know I can assign it to a variable up front, but is that the only way?

```
const key: string[] = [];

const obj = {
  key
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah I guess so.